# Calling a script from a mysql trigger. In real time notification

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql database which contains the status of many orders and where they are located. Im looking for a way to notify my customer on the update of the status of their order.

Basically everytime the column "status" would be changed ( could be done with a trigger of some sort ) , trigger an event that would somehow be able to call an external script (preferably PHP) to either text or email my customer that their order has been updated and that the status is now X, if completed , tell them to come pick it up.

I've read around that triggering script from a mysql trigger is extremely bad pratice but I'm wondering if there are other options to do something like this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no way I know of to have mysql interact with any outside languages. I think a better solution would be using a CRON and PHP script that queries the table of some time interval.

Comment: The thing is I wouldnt be able to know which order status updated from the previous time I checked as far as im aware :(

Comment: You would probably need another column or table to keep track of that. Is there only 1 statuses or a rows status fluctuates?

Comment: Yes, my current implementation only has one row that keeps check of the current status of the order, I doubt I can change the implementation of the table as I am not the one who made the software that use this database. Im only trying to make a notification system for my dad.

Comment: Is it paid/unpaid or something like that will only be modified once? Can you add another table?

Comment: It is unpaid . Im doing my dad and his customer a favor. Yes , I can add other tables.

Comment: Okay so you could make another table, `notifications_set` or whatever and store a time and the id from the other table. You then can join the two tables and select where the status is paid and the notification row is empty.

Comment: Make another table, create a trigger on original table to insert the row into new table each time there is a change of status column. Poll new table via cron and delete each row as you process it

Comment: I think il go ahead and use a 2nd table like both of you suggested and run  cron task to poll my database every few minutes. Thank you all for your help !